# Optional argument with default value in Python

Tags: python, default, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I have seen the optional arguments with deafult value below:

```
def call_parser(type: Optional[str] = None):
```

I am not clear its purpose. If the `type` is provided why do we need to assign default value? Is there any explanation or example related to optional parameter with default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional[str] is equivalent to Union[str, None].

Meaning the variable "type" can take values of type `str` or `None` value.

If you set it to a default value then you don't need to write that variable when calling this function.